# how can i Embed python module in .net?

Tags: python, c#, .net, opencv, python.net

I have made a Ai cursor controller by face land marks by using python open cv, So i need to use this module inside my web browser application that made from .net c# chromium framework. How can i do this , please help me

I need to embed python module inside .net c# project

Comment: Looks like you tagged python.net, a packaged designed for this purpose. Post what you have tried so far, or give that a try first before posting a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use the library directly from C#, you can create a Python based web service and invoke that service from your C# code. Data can be passed back and forth using MessagePack.